# Search text in unstrucutred data

Tags: python, ocr

I have worked on a part of code to read text from images using python. The images are of invoices.

```
import pytesseract as tess
tess.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('C:/Users/Me/Desktop/PM/Invoice Formats/TestInv.png')


text = tess.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

The result of the code is the invoice text. I have multiple invoices with different formats. 
Can anyone please help me how to extract invoice number, invoice date and amount of invoice from these unstructured text?

The text that am getting is somewhat like this for few invoices. For others it is different

```
ABC Manufacturing Corporation





Invoice 1111 HHH BBB
‘MyCity, AB'11111-111'
(111)111-1111
My exporter details
\xyz.com
Page: 1 of 2
invoice No, b123456
Date: 01/02/2019,
‘My Oil Products My Bill-To No. 3333
PO Box 1234, Account Number.: 12345
sdlfjsdlf slsdo

Invoice Summary

Delivery Terms:
Payment Terms:
Contact:

DELIVERY POINT
Net 20 days date of invoice
MY NAME

111-111-1111

111-111-1111
abc@xyz.com
Copies of Invoices and Delivery Notes are available on
my url/ check site/ here.

Hf you have any, further questions relating to, your Invoice,
lease contact MY NAME immediately on
111111111







Quantity - Price uni





1000 KG KM = 1000M — KG = Kilogram
Hours Litre M3 = Cubic meter
EA = Each) Normal Cubic Meter
Pounds 7OF, 1atm)











Product Price |
Product Price 1000.28
Net value 1000.28
Total to be paid INR 80000.28
```

Thnx in advance.

Comment: Can you parse the result of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example to extract the date, you can then extrapolate to extract the others:

```py
date = text.split('Date: ')[1].split(',')[0]
print(date)
```

> '01/02/2019'

Comment: Thank you @Thomas Schillaci. However, the data I have is not all same format. Some places the invoice number header is missing when reading from OCR too.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to handle each case by hand. Otherwise, you can opt for machine learning solutions but this makes the task immediately harder